# The existence of sodium carbide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry, electronic-configuration

(Here, I quote a question from an Indonesian undergraduate Chemistry competition: "sodium carbide reacts with water to form ethyne gas." This is the problem that caused me to ask this question on the site.)

Please provide references of the existence or inexistence of sodium carbide.

Thank you in advance for you who have answered my question.

**Edit 2**: The type of answers I look for are the ones which includes  analysis of probable sodium carbide structures, but deeper explanation will also be highly appreciated.

Thank you to "Community" who suggested an edit to this question.

**Edit 3**: I (Galen) have changed the title of this question and rephrased my question. Thanks to Oscar Lanzi and others who have attempted to answer my question.

Comment: This patent describes the production of sodium carbide from sodium and carbon monoxide  https://patents.google.com/patent/US2642347A/en

Comment: @Waylander , thank you! Through your comment, I also found about Google Patents for the first time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Housecroft and Sharpe give the acid-base reaction of sodium amide with acetylene in liquid ammonia to produce sodium carbide and ammonia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments imply, sodium carbide certainly does exist. However, it is difficult to get because it is only metastable. Therefore it cannot be made from direct combination of the elements in thermodynamically stable form, a procedure often used (in some cases indirectly) with stable binary compounds.

Sodium carbide can be made by using the sodium/CO reaction commented by Waylander (https://patents.google.com/patent/US2642347A/en). This patent gives a brief reference of some other methods:

> It has been proposed to produce sodium carbide by reacting sodium vapor with carbon in an electric arc (German Patent 526,627), by reacting calcium carbide with sodium monoxide or sodium hydroxide (Vaughn U. S. P. 2,156,365) or by reacting metallic sodium with acetylene (British Patent 336,516 of 1930).

Note that in no case is the carbon in a thermodynamically stable form when the carbide is formed; for example without the sodium component the carbon monoxide in the sodium/CO reaction would spontaneously decompose on cooling to the actual carbide formation temperature. In the case of the electric arc the arc takes the carbon (and the sodium) into a higher-energy, metastable state.

Sodium carbide is not alone. Magnesium carbide presents a similar issue.

[Wikipedia](https://m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite_intercalation_compound) gives a curious explanation of the lack of full stability (and thus the impact on possible synthesis techniques) in terms of the related process of forming graphite intercalation compounds:

> Different from other alkali metals, the amount of Na intercalation is very small. Quantum-mechanical calculations show that this originate from a quite general phenomenon: among the alkali and alkaline earth metals, Na and Mg generally have the weakest chemical binding to a given substrate, compared with the other elements in the same group of the periodic table.[1] The phenomenon arises from the competition between trends in the ionization energy and the ion–substrate coupling, down the columns of the periodic table.[1]

**Cited Reference**

1.
Liu, Yuanyue; Merinov, Boris V.; Goddard, William A. (5 April 2016). "Origin of low sodium capacity in graphite and generally weak substrate binding of Na and Mg among alkali and alkaline earth metals". *Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences* **113** (14): 3735–3739. arXiv:1604.03602. Bibcode:2016PNAS..113.3735L. https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1602473113. PMC 4833228. PMID 27001855.

Answer (score 2):

Sodium carbide isn't hypothetical. It does exist and can be synthesized. In @Oscar's answer, there is a patent which shows the synthesis reaction of sodium carbonate and carbon at temperature 1050 °C-1200 °C and contacting the resulting gaseous mixture of carbon monoxide and sodium vapor on steel surface.

There is [another patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2802723A/en) which shows a different synthesis reaction which uses sodium hydroxide. The temperature required is also less:

> The method of forming sodium carbide which comprises reacting a mixture containing free sodium hydroxide and free carbon at temperature of around 700 °C-900 °C and free carbon being in excess of the stoichiometric requirement for the formation of said carbide from said sodium hydroxide.

Moreover, there is one paper ([M S Swapna et al **2017**](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2053-1591/aa9db9/pdf)) which discusses a synthetic route involving a natural precursor, *Pandanus*.

[image]